# How to make Maxima display more digits

Tags: maxima

How do you make Maxima print out all the digits it possibly can?

For example I entered `256^(256);` and maxima returned `323170060713110073007148766886[557 digits]952148193555853611059596230656`. I want it to print all the 557 digits in between, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using wxMaxima, change 2D-display in the Maxima entry of the menu to ascii or none.
You can obtain the same result with
`set_display('ascii)$`
or
`set_display('none)$`

Comment: Later, if you want to restore the default display, you may evaluate `set_display(xml)$`.